# Regular Expression Replace in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to trim the leading and trailing spaces within a div using javascript rgular expression, but it doesn't seem to work. My code is as below. You can try this code at [Online Javascript Testing](http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~ovens/javascript/jstester.html). My goal is to remove all spaces before and after **abc 123**, but within the enclosing the div.

```
var h = "<div>    abc  123    </div>";
h = h.replace(new RegExp("\\<div\\>\\s*\\<\\/div\\>", "gi"), "");
alert(h);
```

Comment: I am getting the original string even after using my code. I should actually just get: <div>abc  123</div>

Comment: What do you think it should be ? Remove the double slashes throughout?

Comment: I don't understand why you feel the need to do this because the `<div>` will not display the leading or trailing spaces anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth noting that as HTML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), you can't reliably operate on HTML fragments with regular expressions except when you have a very narrow, defined scope. For instance, here, we can do this if the text really is as you show, but not (reliably) if there are nested divs (for that we'd need more than just a regular expression).

With that out of the way:

I would use a literal rather than a string passed into the `RegExp` constructor. It just makes things a bit simpler. Then I'd use a capture group and substitute the content of the group for the overall match. And you need a rule after the text you want to match to consume the whitespace at the end. That means the rule in the middle needs to be non-greedy. All of which comes to:

```
var h = "<div>    dsd  dsdsd    </div>";
h = h.replace(/<div>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/div>/gi, "$1");
alert("'" + h + "'");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ahasit) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ahasit/edit)

Or if you want to keep the `div` tags:

```
var h = "<div>    dsd  dsdsd    </div>";
h = h.replace(/(<div>)\s*(.*?)\s*(<\/div>)/gi, "$1$2$3");
alert(h);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ahasit/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ahasit/2/edit)

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: that will remove the div and keep the inner text you shouldve written h.replace(/(<div>)\s*(.*?)\s*(<\/div>)/gi, "$1$2$3");

Comment: i wanted to keep the div and simply trim leading/trailing spaces within a div. your second sample code is the answer. thanks. excellent answer.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that, if there are nested divs, using `.*?` can cause problems: `<div> a <div> b </div>c</div>` would produce `<div>a <div> b</div>c</div>`. There's no general solution for nesting (not a regular language), but at least using `[^<]*?` instead will fail fast in case of nesting, instead of producing an incorrect result (it would only do the replacement for the innermost div).

Answer (score 2):

You could use capturing groups to get the contents. BTW, why use the `RegExp` function and not a literal? You'd have to type less `\`s...

```
h = h.replace(/<div>\s*([^<]*?)\s*<\/div>/g, "<div>$1</div>");
```

The `[^<]*?` will lazily match anything that's not an `<` (including spaces). Since it's lazy, all blank spaces immediatly before the closing tag will not be included.

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/WZNWd/)

(Be careful of nested html though... If your tags can be nested, better not use regex for it)